# A nowhere vanishing vector field on odd spheres

Tags: differential-geometry

It is a renamed theorem the existence of a nowhere vanishing vector fields on odd dimensional spheres. Now, in his textbook, L. Tu proposes the following exercise:

> Let $x^1,y^1,\dots,x^n,y^n$ be the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and consider the unit sphere $S^{2n-1}$ (defined by the equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x^i)^2+(y^i)^2=1$ and the vector field
> $$
> X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n -y^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}+x^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}
> $$
> on $S^{2n-1}$.

It is a very simple exercise to check that it does not vanish in any point. I have only to show that it is smooth.

Googling a bit, I found a textbook of solutions by Richard Ligo [just write on google "Solutions an introduction to manifolds Tu"]

In this post, such a solution has been analyzed.

[Vector field on an odd sphere. $X = \sum_{i=1}^n -y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + x^i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$ is smooth.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264235/vector-field-on-an-odd-sphere-x-sum-i-1n-yi-frac-partial-partial-x)

I'd like to better understand the solution. Various things are strange for me and I do not find satisfactory the questions given to this post.

My notations will refer to Ligo's solution. Set $t^{21-i}:=x^i$ and $t^{2i}:=y^i$ for every $i=1,\dots,n$. Then

$$
X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n-1} (-t^{i+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial t^i}+t^i\frac{\partial}{\partial t^{i+1}})
$$
There was a typo in Ligo's solution, where the indexing stopped at $2n$, which is impossible.

Next, we shall use the stereographic projection atlas on $S^{2n-1}$. Idea of the proof: to show the existence of an atlas such that for any of its coordinate neighborhood $U \subseteq S^{2n-1}$ we can write $X=\sum\limits a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}$, with $a_i$ are $C^\infty$ functions on  $U$.

Set $z^i=\frac{t^i}{1-t^{2n}}$. In the last answer to the proposed post, you can textually read

> In order to obtain the desired relation above between vectors on $S^{2n-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$ you want to use the pushforward of the charts corresponding to stereographic projections. Given a smooth map $f:M\rightarrow N$ between two manifolds, this induces another map $f_\ast:T_pM\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$, mapping a vector from the tangent space at $p\in M$ to one at $f(p)\in N$. Note that $M$ and $N$ do not necessarily have the same dimension. This map is defined in the following way:

> Let $g\in C^{\infty}(N,\mathbb{R})$, so $g\circ f\in C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$. A vector $X\in T_pM$ acts on $g\circ f$ and takes it to a number. Now, we define $f_\ast(X)\in T_{f(p)}N$ such that
> $$f_\ast(X)[g]=X[g\circ f].$$
> In terms of charts $(U,\phi),(V,\psi)$ on $M,N$ respectively, this becomes
> $$f_\ast(X)[g\circ\psi^{-1}(y)]=X[g\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}(x)]$$ with $x=\phi(p)$ and $y=\psi(f(p))$. If we rewrite $X=X^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $f_\ast(X)=Y^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$ then the above yields
> $$Y^j=X^i\frac{\partial y^j(x)}{\partial x^i}.$$
> But this is precisely what is used in your solution. In your case, $M=S^{2n-1}$ and $N=\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$ with e.g. $$f:S^{2n-1}\backslash\{(0,\dots,1)\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}, (t_1,\dots,t_{2n})\mapsto\frac{1}{1-t_{2n}}(t_1,\dots,t_{2n-1})$$
> the chart excluding the north pole. Applying the procedure above to this, you can rewrite a vector given on the sphere in terms of the local coordinates given via stereographic projections.

It is very unclear how the previous answer is used in the previous example to get EXACTLY the equality (for $i=1,\dots,2n$, I think!)

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t^i}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{\partial z_k}{\partial t^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^k}
$$

Someone answered me in the comments: it is a consequence of the chain rule. Yes, if the charts were defined on the same manifold. But the coordinates $t^1,\dots,t^{2n}$ are coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (dimension 2n) and $z^1,\dots,z^{2n-1}$ are coordinates of $S^{2n-1}$ (dimension $2n-1$).

Such an objection is the topic of the aforementioned post and the quoted answer tries to make use of the push-forward of the differential, in a very strong way. Please, it is possible to see in GREAT DETAIL (and without misleading hints or half answers with much implied content!) a proof of the equality

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t^i}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{\partial z_k}{\partial t^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial z^k} ?
$$

In the below comment, $k$ goes from $1$ to $2n$, but how is it possible, if $S^{2n-1}$ has dimension $2n-1$? The index $i$ goes from $1$ to $2n$. This goes me a bit confused on how the chain rule works.